# Bash : find all IP addresses that have been used for a non-autorised access attempt

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on my virtual machine on bash. I am asked to find all ip addresses that have been used for an attempt to access the machine without authorization, using the auth.log file. I do not seem to find any answer to my problem. Here is an example : [image]

all returned lines must be written in my shared file /mnt/analyse/traitement/cueillette.txt. Please help ! Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to U&L, what have you tried so far Peter ?

Comment: I have tried -sudo su root                                                                                                              -cat /media/sf_partageAuth/auth.log | grep "authentification failure" | grep [0-9] > /mnt/analyse/traitement/cueillette.txt so basically filtering the error then redirect the error to my txt file. Error is "grep authentification failure : command not found

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pipe grep into grep (that's almost always a sign that you are taking an inefficient, misguided approach.  `sed` alone is enough for this task. or `awk`. or `perl`), and that `sudo su root cat` is just nonsense.

Try this:

```bsh
$ sudo sed -n -E -e '/sshd.*authentication failure/{s/^.*rhost=([0-9.]+).*/\1/p}' \ 
    /media/sf_partageAuth/auth.log > /mnt/analyse/traitement/cueillette.txt
```

For every line that matches "authentication failure" (note, **not** "authenti**fi**cation"), this `sed` script removes everything from the beginning of the line up to (and including) `rhost=`, and everything after the IP address, then prints the line.

It uses `sed`'s `-E` option for extended regular expressions, so that `()` and `+` work without needing to be escaped.

Note that while the `sed` command is run as root with `sudo`, the output redirection is not - that's done in your original non-root shell.  If you need root privileges to write to the output file too, run `tee` with `sudo`, e.g.:

```bsh
$ sudo sed -n -E -e '/sshd.*authentication failure/{s/^.*rhost=([0-9.]+).*/\1/p}' \
    /media/sf_partageAuth/auth.log | 
    sudo tee /mnt/analyse/traitement/cueillette.txt > /dev/null
```